# В чем отлаживать php скрипты?

Tags: php, zend-studio

Столкнулся с таким вопросом, хотелось бы Zend Server, но ключа к нему нету.

Или можно как-нибудь Zend Studio подключить к денверу или другому локальному веб-серваку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/):

> It is completely free, and you can use it in development, testing and production.

Вдобавок: [PHP Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef), [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), [XDEBUG](http://xdebug.org/) - [How To Setup](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/HowToSetupDevelopmentEnvironmentWindows).

Answer (score 1):

Использую [phpDesigner](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php), очень нравится. Перепробовал всё от дримвивера до зенд, остановил свой выбор на phpDesigner.

Answer (score 0):

Ящитаю самое простое решение - построить доказательство соответствия спецификациям с помощью автопрувера ([Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/), [Agda2](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), [Epigram](http://www.e-pig.org/)).

Comment: Можете пояснить?

Comment: Что именно? Тут все прозрачно: взял аксиоматику, взял спеки, ну а дальше по накатанной.